# UI becomes non responding after getting from in to the main queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, lazy-loading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to have the lazy loading of images from a url and updating the UI once the image is received in the main queue only , the UI is getting updated but the view becomes unresponsive , I am using GCD to create a new thread for getting the data from the URL

let imageUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: SiteAPIURL + (DEFAULTS.valueForKey(kInviterImageUrl) as! String))!

```
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
    SwiftLoader.show(title: "Loading", animated: true)


    let queue  : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)

  dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
    let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)!
    let image = UIImage(data: data)!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.userImage.image   = image
        self.userImageWide.image = image

    })



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH: Items dispatched to the queue run at high priority; the queue is scheduled for execution before any default priority or low priority queue."
thats from the documentation so use something else with less priority as this one may block the default queue, like QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED. 
This does what you wanted

```
    if let url = imageUrl{
        let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0), {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if data != nil {
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                        self.userImage.image   = image
                        self.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        self.userImageWide.image = image
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
```